# Part of capital letter N is missing in ylabel in pngcairo format in gnuplot

Tags: png, gnuplot, axis-labels

I have a problem with capital letter N in ylabel, specifically, part of the letter is missing. The same label works fine when applied in xlabel.

This problem appears when using PNGCAIRO terminal (It works fine for eps and jpeg formats).

I would like to use the pngcairo format. So is there a way to fix this problem?

Code:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 600,400 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output "Nproblem.png"
set datafile separator ","
# color definitions
set colorsequence default
set style line 1 lc 3 lt 1 lw 2 dt 3 # --- red
set xlabel 'Next N n M|M| N|N| (N/N)'
set ylabel 'Next n N M|M| N|N| (N/N)'
set grid 
plot "EMS_term_magnitude_comparison_400A_1.8Hz_center.csv" u ($5+0.13):(sqrt($1*$1+$2*$2+$3*$3)) w l ls 1 t 'N'
set out 
reset
```

PNG figure with missing N in ylabel:

[image]

Jpeg figure or how I would like the ylabel to look like:

[image]

Comment: That's a bug (you can try different fonts, they all look deformed in the cairo-based terminals y-axis) I think i have seen before. Rotated labels have the same problem: `set label 2 "NNNNNNNN" at -3,-3 rotate by 90`, and it looks the same in gp 5.2pl3 and 5.0pl6.

Comment: In the meantime, you can use the `png` terminal, it has the same routines as jpeg and looks good. As does `pdfcairo`, most likely because pdf leaves the text rotation to the viewer.

Comment: This must be platform-specific; I see no such artifact using gnuplot 5.2.2 on OS X with pango 4001.14.0 and cairo 11403.12.0. Could you post the output of the `test` command using the `pngcairo` terminal?

Comment: @user8153 I also use gnuplot 5.2.2. on Windows 10 Pro. The output for test command in pngcairo: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/ptBT2JR.png)

Comment: It is probably a bug, but verdana is M$ font, have you tried a non-windows one?

Answer (score 0):

This weird and annoying behaviour can still be observed with gnuplot 5.4.1
As mentioned in the comments this probably might depend on many things: terminal, gnuplot version, OS, font, fontsize, maybe on terminal size and others.
So, I can reproduce this with gnuplot 5.4.1 on Win10 on wxt terminal. It looks like this only happens with the standard fontsize which is 10 in my case.

However, it seems, you can workaround it if you specify `font sprintf('",%d"',10)` instead of default size or `font ",10"`.
This is pretty strange but maybe someone has an explanation for this?

**Code:**

```
### disappearing horizontal lines in labels
reset session

myText(i) = sprintf("%g pt: %s",i,'HHH III MMM NNN |||')
set nokey

set title "Example:\nfontsize 10: yes\nfontsize 11: no" left
set ylabel  myText(10) font ",10"
set y2label myText(11) font ",11"
plot x

pause -1

set title "Workaround:\nfont sprintf('\",%d\"',10): no\nfont \",10\": yes" left
set ylabel  myText(10) font sprintf('",%d"',10)
set y2label myText(10) font ",10"
plot x

### end of code
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]